Webhook for AppSumo
I am trying to create a Webhook for my AppSumo account.
I have in my code this PHP code (for me to see what kind of incoming data is passing through on purchase) :
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'config.php';

ini_set("error_log", "appsumo.errors.log.txt");

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
if ($data == "") die("No data");
print_r($data);

$file = fopen('appsumo-webhook-data.txt', "a");
fwrite($file, $data.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);

But I can't seem to validate it (https://myDomain.test/appsumo.php) at AppSumo because I need to respond it with 3 events.
Webhook URL: Pre-validate by receiving a POST request with a field called test in the body.
This URL must return a 200 OK with a JSON response indicating success = true and the event type it received.
For the initial test, you must respond to/with the following event types:
activate
deactivate
purchase (optional)

What do I have to do to respond it with the 3 events above ?

I don't know if I should delete this post or not because I got this solved using https://app.commanddash.io/agent/samyakkkk_App_Sumo -

Write an Answer below showing what you did to solve it. Then others on stackoverflow can be helped too
